# How to change selenium encoding to utf-8

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, encoding, webdriver

While running code I am getting this error only if characters are in Georgian. In English I have no problem. How can this error can be fixed?

**`მობილური კავშირი`** having here Georgian letters is a problem, if there go English everything works fine.

```
from selenium import webdriver
 #-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import time


driver  = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://tbcpay.ge/")
driver.find_element_by_link_text('მობილური კავშირი').click()
```

Comment: At which line are you getting the error?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you were almost there. You need to replace the lowercase `utf` to uppercase **`UTF`** i.e. the line would be:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it still doesn't work. I also tried "driver.find_element_by_link_text('მობილური კავშირი').encode("utf-8")" but still having same problem.

still same error
  File "C:\Users\ALEX\Desktop\pythontest\seleniumtest.py", line 9, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_link_text('მობილური კავშირი')